# How to pass a value of outer class to a @Nested @Test int JUnit 5?

Tags: junit5

i have `OuterTest` with this code:

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
private Service Service;

@InjectMocks
private RestController RestController;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = standaloneSetup(RestController)
            .build();
}
```

and i have a nested class, with tests, that repeated over my project for few times, but need to be tested at all of my controllers separately

```
     @Nested
     public class RepeatableTest extends repeatableTestSuite {

            }
        }
```

this is the test case, that repeated all over project

```
@Test
void repeatableTestCase_shouldFailTest(MockMvc mockMvc, String url, Service service) throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(post(url, INVALID_VALUE))
                    .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())

            verifyZeroInteractions(service);
        }
```

this test fails, because it need MockMvc and URL, created and configured at outer class, how may i do this?

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to define `protected MockMvc mockMvc` in `repeatableTestSuite`
and then in `@Nested` class

```
@Nested
public class RepeatableTest extends RepeatableTestSuite {

        @BeforeEach
        void setUp() {
            mockMvc = OuterClassTest.this.mockMvc;
            url = OuterClassTest.URL;
            service = OuterClassTest.this.service;
        }
    }
```